# call function on imploded value?

Tags: php, function, implode

I have an array of values, the values are all in lower case, I want to call `ucfirst()` on the values.

I could do

```
function uc_implode($values){
    foreach($values as &$v)
        $v = ucfirst($v);
    return $values;
}

echo implode(', ', uc_implode($values));
```

But I am wondering if there is any way to just call `ucfirst()` on each value as it is imploded?

Comment: There is no callback or hook exposed by `lmpload()` to allow this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could do:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map("ucfirst", $values));
```